# Stop threads created by Android Service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I currently have an app which when a button is pressed starts a service and within the service a thread is created. 
I then have a second button (which appears once the first it pressed) that should shut down the service and in turn kill the thread, below is my current code however the service seems to stop but the thread keeps going.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static  Button              lock            = null;
    private static  Button              unlock          = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lock = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.lock);
        unlock = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.unlock);


        lock.setOnClickListener(btn_lock);
        unlock.setOnClickListener(btn_unlock);

        unlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        text.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        startService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
    }


    private OnClickListener btn_lock = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                unlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class));

        }
    };

    private OnClickListener btn_unlock = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                unlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class));
        }
    };


}
```

And then my service class looks like:

```
public class MainService extends Service {

    Thread 1Thread;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        1Thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                    while(true){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(180000); // 3 minutes
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.i("TEST", "Thread is still here!");
                }
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        1Thread.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        1Thread.start();
    }

}
```

Hope someone can help and if you need any more info let me know!

Comment: why do you have a while nested inside another while?

Comment: Try using stopSelf() instead of stopService

Comment: @blackbelt the double while was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  boolean mStatus = true;

   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        1Thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (mStatus) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(180000); // 3 minutes
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            continue;

                        }
                        Log.i("TEST", "Thread is still here!");

            }
        };


    }



@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         mStatus = false;
         1Thread.interrupt();
    }
```

Comment: But when the button is clicked will this not wait to kill the thread after the 3 minutes of sleep? I need the threads to die right away

Comment: if you call 1Thread.interrupt(); the InterruptedException will be thrown

Comment: ah ok! perfect shall test it now

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is not handling `interrupt`, in `while` loop in each iteration check if thread is `interrupted`, if so then do not continue the loop:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(180000); // 3 minutes
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
break; //BREAK here, as thread was interrupted
                        }
                        Log.i("TEST", "Thread is still here!");
}
```

Also on click of second button, you should interrupt this thread:

```
1Thread.interrupt();
```